# Running Autoprefixer with BundleTransformer / LESS in Debug mode

Tags: asp.net, less, autoprefixer, bundletransformer

So I currently use `BundleTransformer`, `LESS` and I'm trying to add the `Autoprefixer` post processor. This plugin automatically takes css like `transform: scale(1.5)` and converts it to `-webkit-transform` and `-moz-transform`.

If I am in release mode or have `BundleTable.EnableOptimizations=true` then everything works just fine and the prefixes are added as expected.

In debug mode however, all the individual CSS / LESS files in my bundle are present in the HTML as separate requests. I'm using this command in my CSHTML file:

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css/lessbundle")
```

i.e. In debug mode this gets expanded out to `LINK` tags for  :

```
/cs/something.css
/css/lessfile1.less
/css/lessfile1.less
```

instead of a single file

```
/Content/css/lessbundle?v=RFAUSIwb-jEuuo4vHNTnTkE2LrN2jfHglX-Hk8HIF481
```

For the LESS files IIS automatically converts them, however it does not apply the `Autoprefixer`.

Is there a way to get Autoprefixer to work when requesting raw `.css` and `.less` files?

If not it seems kind of pointless to me because the only alternative I see is to request directly the `'Content/css/lessbundle` virtual URL - which will get run through the `Autoprefixer`. It will only get minified for a release build.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the documentation (sections: [“Examples of usage”](https://bundletransformer.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Examples%20of%20usage), [“Debugging HTTP-handlers”](https://bundletransformer.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Debugging%20HTTP-handlers) and [“Postprocessors”](https://bundletransformer.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Postprocessors)) describes how to solve this problem. I will list the basic steps:

1. For debugging HTTP-handlers to use a configuration settings from    bundles need to add in the `RegisterBundles` method of    `App_Start/BundleConfig.cs` file the following code:

   BundleResolver.Current = new CustomBundleResolver();
2. In order to these settings can be applied to CSS- and JS-assets need    to register the debugging HTTP-handlers `CssAssetHandler` and    `JsAssetHandler` in Web.config file. To do this in the IIS Integrated mode, you need add to the `/configuration/system.webServer/handlers` element the following code:

   <add name="CssAssetHandler"
       path="*.css" verb="GET"
       type="BundleTransformer.Core.HttpHandlers.CssAssetHandler, BundleTransformer.Core"
       resourceType="File" preCondition="" />

   <add name="JsAssetHandler"
       path="*.js" verb="GET"
       type="BundleTransformer.Core.HttpHandlers.JsAssetHandler, BundleTransformer.Core"
       resourceType="File" preCondition="" />
3. To make `AutoprefixCssPostProcessor` is one of the default CSS-postprocessors, you need to make changes to the `Web.config` file. In the `defaultPostProcessors` attribute of `\configuration\bundleTransformer\core\css` element must be add `AutoprefixCssPostProcessor` to end of comma-separated list (for example,  `defaultPostProcessors="UrlRewritingCssPostProcessor,AutoprefixCssPostProcessor"`).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what @Taritsyn said you need to make sure your bundles are

`CustomScriptBundle()` and not `ScriptBundle()`

If not you will get the slightly confusing error message:

> Could not find the transformer in the '~/Content/css/myCssBundle' bundle.

---

I found it interesting to look deeper into how this actually works

The HTML is written (just view source) with an additional parameter `?bundleVirtualPath`

```
/Content/css/defenderrazor_DEBUG.less?
bundleVirtualPath=~%2fContent%2fcss%2fmyCssBundle
```

This is intercepted by the handler in the `web.config` when a .less file is requested and the handler is then able to use that bundle name to look up any transformations that you've set - including in this case the default post processor for `AutoprefixCss`.